# Force url to use www

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, url-rewriting, no-www

I'm confused about how to force my url to use www in the address.

I have a .htaccess code like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm changing

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I still get an error.

The page isn't redirecting properly when I open `http://www.mysite.com/category`

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess looks like you are using Wordpress. Is this true? If that is the case, just go to Settings -> General and change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to versions with 'www'.